# Why do some tables in Lua display differently when print(sometable) is called on them?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm confused by behavior I'm seeing when I use luaxml to parse an XML string.  The Lua doc states that calling print() on a table variable as such:

```
print(type(t))  
print(t)
```

will result in output like this:

```
t2:        table  
t2:        table: 0095CB98
```

However, when I use luaxml as such:

```
require "luaxml"

s = "<a> <first> 1st </first> <second> 2nd </second> </a>"  
t = xml.eval(s)

print("t:       ", type(t))  
print("t:       ", t)
```

I get the following output:

```
t:        table  
t:        <a>  
  <first>1st</first>    
  <second>2nd</second>  
</a>
```

Why does `print(t)` not return a result that looks like the first example?

Answer (score 5):

The `print` function uses `tostring` to convert its arguments to strings.

When `tostring` is called with a table, and the table's metatable has a `__tostring` field, then `tostring` calls the corresponding value with the table as an argument, and uses the result of the call as its result.

I suspect that luaxml has such a `__tostring` metamethod on the table returned from `xml.eval(s)`.

Comment: I suspected something of this nature was the case, but didn't know print() behaved in this fashion.  Is there a way to "reflect" (not sure if that term has meaning here) on the table object in question to see its metamethods?

Comment: I'll answer my own question since your answer above lead me to a solution:

    mt = getmetatable(t)  
    for key, value in pairs(mt) do print(key, value) end

will print the metamethods....

And 

    setmetatable(t, nil) removes it if need be as well  

Thanks!  
-Gerald

Comment: Btw, if anyone reading this is using luaxml be advised that the table returned by xml.eval() is indexed starting with 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the function `__tostring` on a table's metatable to get this result. When you pass that table to print(), if you have a `__tostring` function on your metatable, print() will output the result of evaluating that function instead of using the default method (which just prints the memory address of the table).